# Pandas: map dates accross x-axis to y-axis in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, parsing

Given the following CSV file (in a DataFrame through `pandas.from_csv(...)`:

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| country | 02/11/20 | 03/11/20 | 04/11/20 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| Norway  |     5100 |     5200 |     5300 |
| Sweden  |     6100 |     6200 |     6300 |
| Finland |     4100 |     4200 |     4300 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

How could I turn this into the following using `pandas` in python:

```
+----------+---------+------------+
|   date   | country | population |
+----------+---------+------------+
| 02/11/20 | Norway  |       5100 |
| 03/11/20 | Norway  |       5200 |
| 04/11/20 | Norway  |       5300 |
| 02/11/20 | Sweden  |       6100 |
| 03/11/20 | Sweden  |       6200 |
| 04/11/20 | Sweden  |       6300 |
| 02/11/20 | Finland |       4100 |
| 03/11/20 | Finland |       4200 |
| 04/11/20 | Finland |       4300 |
+----------+---------+------------+
```

So essentially map the dates on the x-axis to the y-axis.

Comment: Is 'country' in the index or the first column of your dataframe?

Comment: It is the first column @ScottBoston

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.melt('country', var_name='date', value_name='population')
```

Output:

```
     country      date  population
0   Norway    02/11/20        5100
1   Sweden    02/11/20        6100
2   Finland   02/11/20        4100
3   Norway    03/11/20        5200
4   Sweden    03/11/20        6200
5   Finland   03/11/20        4200
6   Norway    04/11/20        5300
7   Sweden    04/11/20        6300
8   Finland   04/11/20        4300
```

Comment: That was surprisingly easy! Clean and good solution, and it works.